# Calculate PQ if AC = 20

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: Geometry problem]

I need to calculate $PQ$ knowing that $AC = 20$.

This is what I got so far: If I call the point between $P$ and $A$, "$M$" and If I call the angle:

$$\measuredangle{QPB} = y$$

Then:

$$\measuredangle{BMA} = \measuredangle{PMC} = y$$

And if we call the point between $C$ and $P$, "$N$", then:

$$ \measuredangle{NCP} = \measuredangle{NPC} = x$$

So there are two isosceles triangles $\triangle CNP$ and $\triangle PNM$. $CN = NM$.

I think the triangles $\triangle CPB$ and $\triangle CAB$ are congruent because they are both rectangle triangles and possess the same hypotenuse, but I don't know how to prove it. I tried working with the angles and their Cosines, but the it gets way too hard.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: All we can say is that $PQ = 20 \sin x \cos x = 10\sin 2x$. Unless $x$ is fixed, you can't determine $PQ$.

Comment: It comes as a surprise that $PQ$ does not depend on $x$. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that $\widehat{ABC}=2x$. Then
$$PQ = BP\sin x = BC \cos x\sin x = AC\frac{\sin x\cos x}{\sin(2x)} = \frac {AC}{2}=10.$$

As an alternative, notice that $B,A,P,C$ all lie on the circle $\Gamma$ having $BC$ as a diameter. Since $BP$ bisects $\widehat{ABC}$, $P$ is the midpoint of the minor arc $AC$ on $\Gamma$. This gives that $P$, the midpoint $M$ of $AC$ and the midpoint $O$ of $BC$ (that is the center of $\Gamma$) are collinear. If we take $R$ as the symmetric of $P$ with respect to $\Gamma$, we have that $BPCR$ is a rectangle, hence $BPC$ is congruent to $PCR$ and $PQ$ and $CM$ have the same length. This happen also because both $CM$ and $PQ$ are the heights of an isosceles triangle, $OPC$.

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Btw I think you mean that P is the midpoint of the minor arc AC.